# Simple Inherit from class in Python throws error

Tags: python, inheritance

Hi I just started with Python, I'm currently developing a UI testing application for mobile devices and I have to work on a custom rendered Softkeyboard.

Button.py

```
class Button():
    def __init__(self, name, x, y, x2=None, y2=None):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
```

KeyboardKey.py

```
import Button
class KeyboardKey(Button):
    def __init__(self, name, x, y):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(name, x, y)
```

That's my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thomas/.../KeyboardKey.py", line 2, in 
    class KeyboardKey(Button):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you do in your code, you inherit from module `Button`, not a class. You should inherit class `Button.Button` instead.

In order to avoid this in future, I strongly suggest to name modules with lowercase, and capitalize classes. So, better naming would be:

```
import button
class KeyboardKey(button.Button):
    def __init__(self, name, x, y):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(name, x, y)
```

Modules in python are normal objects (of type [`types.ModuleType`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.ModuleType)), can be inherited, and have `__init__` method:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.__init__
<method-wrapper '__init__' of module object at 0x00AB5630>
```

See usage:

```
>>> base64.__init__('modname', 'docs here')
>>> base64.__doc__
'docs here'
>>> base64.__name__
'modname'
```

Comment: Alternately, he could do: `from Button import Button`.

Comment: @iCodez agree, but as I prefer other way, I choose to fix inheritance part, not import.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, now i got a lot of renaming to do, just wrote about 15 classes before I even startet to check for errors :P